Is there a way to calculate "suggestedMaxPriorityFeePerGas and suggestedMaxFeePerGas", same way the INFURA Gas API do for BNB Network
The Infura Gas API response for bnb net :
{
  "low": {
    "suggestedMaxPriorityFeePerGas": "4.7",
    "suggestedMaxFeePerGas": "4.7",
    "minWaitTimeEstimate": 15000,
    "maxWaitTimeEstimate": 60000
  },
  "medium": {
    "suggestedMaxPriorityFeePerGas": "4.85",
    "suggestedMaxFeePerGas": "4.85",
    "minWaitTimeEstimate": 15000,
    "maxWaitTimeEstimate": 45000
  },
  "high": {
    "suggestedMaxPriorityFeePerGas": "4.9",
    "suggestedMaxFeePerGas": "4.9",
    "minWaitTimeEstimate": 15000,
    "maxWaitTimeEstimate": 30000
  },
  "estimatedBaseFee": "0.0",
  "networkCongestion": 0,
  "latestPriorityFeeRange": [
    "4.85",
    "4.85"
  ],
  "historicalPriorityFeeRange": [
    "4.85",
    "5"
  ],
  "historicalBaseFeeRange": [
    "0",
    "0"
  ],
  "priorityFeeTrend": "down",
  "baseFeeTrend": "down",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}

suggestedMaxPriorityFeePerGas returned by API for low, medium and high are not static.
My question is how can I calculate the suggestedMaxFeePerGas when suggestedMaxPriorityFeePerGas is dynamic and the baseFee is zero too (not just in this case. it's always zero, for BNB).
I'm a beginner and what I know is that the
MaxFeePerGas = BaseFeePerGas + MaxPriorityFeePerGas
But in this case baseFeePerGas is 0  &  MaxPriorityFeePerGas is dynamic (which I can't figure out, how to calculate)

Please include the response as text instead of a screenshot. This helps for searching and accessibility.

@ryanwebjackson Done.
